# answer interactive prompt from docker container ran in script (certbot)

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, docker, certbot

So I tried searching far and wide and I can't seem to get what I'm trying to do to work.

Essentially I have a script that runs a certbot docker container with the digital ocean plugin.  I can run the container with the --agree-tos argument so that it automatically agrees to just about everything BUT the email sharing question, no matter what I do I still get the would you like to share your email prompt and I want my script to answer yes/no automatically.

I think it would be easier if I show what's going on:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Move old certificates to another folder
docker run -it --rm --name certbot \
-v "/srv/scripts/new/new:/etc/letsencrypt" \
-v "/srv/scripts/digitalocean.ini:/digitalocean.ini" \
certbot/dns-digitalocean:arm64v8-latest certonly --dns-digitalocean  \
--dns-digitalocean-credentials /digitalocean.ini \
--dns-digitalocean-propagation-seconds 360 \
-m myemail@gmail.com --agree-tos \
-d mydomain.com -d \*.mydomain.com
# Move new certs to the correct location and delete temp files etc
```

Now this works fine and dandy however I can't automate this because I need to answer yes or no to the "Would you like to share your email with letsencrtypt?" question.

I tried running `echo "Y" | ./myscript.sh` or even adding the `echo "n"` into my script however I can't get it to answer automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work when you pipe it through `yes`: `yes | ...`?

Comment: yes, yes it does .... thank you so much ... but why wouldnt echo work?

Comment: maybe it expects lowercase `y`?

Comment: `yes` command output the string `yes` repeatedly [until it stops](https://www.howtogeek.com/415535/how-to-use-the-yes-command-on-linux/), either because you pressed ctrl+c, or the process at the other side of the pipe terminates. It is possible your "yes" from the echo was caught or got lost too early before the actual question appeared.

Comment: Or maybe, as @ArkadiuszDrabczyk said, it was expecting a different text and not an uppercase Y.

Comment: By the way, have you tried `--eff-email` or `--no-eff-email` arguments to the command?